# How i run Github workflow in sequential manner?

Tags: github-actions

I want to run my GitHub workflow in a sequential manner. to explain it better, once the previous workflow is completed only then does the next one gets started rather than both running at the same time. can we achieve that?

[image]

Comment: You can configure [`workflow_run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) event for the workflow(s) that depend on the completion, i.e. `completed` type, of other workflow(s).

Answer (score 1):

In Github Actions world, this is called "job concurrency". you can effect this by specifying `jobs.<job_id>.concurrency` to ensure that only a single job or workflow using the same concurrency group will run at a time.

For more info and examples, please visit the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency)